# Uncheck checkbox value always at the bottom of the list in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I have a table with checkoxes. I use array to handle this. But somehow after submit. The uncheck values always at the bottom of the list in mysql. Here is my code:

```
$mystudentID = $_POST['studID']; 
$mystudATT = $_POST['myattt']; 
$number = count($mystudentID ); 

for ($i=0; $i<$number; $i++) 
{
    $studID = $mystudentID[$i]; 
    $studAtt = $mystudATT[$i]; 

    $sql="
        INSERT INTO mate_student_att
        (attendance,date,studID) 
        VALUES 
        ('$studAtt','$_POST[myDate]','$studID')
    ";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";
} 
mysqli_close($con);
```

Please help

Comment: question is not clear sir

Comment: What I mean is my unchecked box never got into my array. How do we store uncheck value to the mysql db

Comment: unchecked checkboxes does not get transmitted via form post, the absence of the given checkbox is the determination of it being unchecked

Comment: Yeah, I just learned about that. Is there anywhere to work around this?

Comment: my previous comment has the way around it written too. There is no way around changing the form post behavior you have to adjust your code by figuring out when checkboxes are absent, they are unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

DevZer0 is right.
The only way to keep all of your check boxes into your db is to create a hidden field into your html form with all check boxes displayed (no matter what is their initial of final status). 
For example you might keep all check box names like this

```
 studID1,studID2,studID3,studID4
```

in the hidden field's value. 
This hidden field will be posted. 
Then you have to split/explode your hidden field's value in order to get an array with the name of your check boxes. 
You loop into this array and if the name of each check box name is found in your post parameters it means that his check box was checked and you insert it into your db with attendance 1, otherwise you insert it into your db with attendance 0.
I can change your code accordingly if you cant get it done.

**EDIT**

Your form

```
<input type='hidden' name='allStudIDs' value='studID1,studID2,studID3,studID4,studID5,studID6,studID7' />
<input type='checkbox' name='studID1" />student 1
<input type='checkbox' name='studID2" />student 2
<input type='checkbox' name='studID3" />student 3
<input type='checkbox' name='studID4" />student 4
<input type='checkbox' name='studID5" />student 5
<input type='checkbox' name='studID6" />student 6
<input type='checkbox' name='studID7" />student 7
```

and your script after post

```
$allStudentIDs = $_POST['allStudIDs']; 
$mystudentID = $_POST['studID']; 
$tempArray = explode(",", $allStudentIDs);

for ($i=0; $i<count($tempArray); $i++) 
{
    $studID = $tempArray[$i];
    if (isset($_POST[$tempArray[$i]])) 
    {
        $studAtt = 1; 
    }
    else
    {
        $studAtt = 0; 
    }

    $sql="
        INSERT INTO mate_student_att
        (attendance,date,studID) 
        VALUES 
        ('$studAtt','$_POST[myDate]','$studID')
    ";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";
} 
mysqli_close($con);
```